# Solving leaky memory and syntax issues in a simple hash table

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm implementing a basic hashtable. My logic for the table makes sense (at least to me), but I'm a bit rusty with my C++. My program returns a free memory error when I run it, but I can't seem to figure out where my problem is. I think is has to do with how I call the pointers in the various class functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

int hashU(string in/*, int M*/){            //hThe hash function that utilizes a smal pseusorandom number
    char *v = new char[in.size() + 1];      //generator to return an number between 0 and 50. (I arbitrarily chose 50 as the upper limit)
    copy(in.begin(), in.end(), v);          //First the input string is turned into a char* for use in the the function.
    v[in.size()] = '\0';

    int h, a = 31415, b = 27183;
    for(h=0;*v!=0;v++,a=a*b%(49-1))
        h = (a*h + *v)%50;

    delete[] v;                             //Delete the char* to prevent leaky memory.
    return (h<0) ? (h+50) : h;              //Return number
}

struct hashNode{                            //The node that will store the key and the values
    string key;
    float val;

    struct hashNode *next;
};

struct hashLink{                            //The linked list that will store additional keys and values should there be a collision.
    public:
    struct hashNode *start;                 //Start pointer
    struct hashNode *tail;                  //Tail pointer

    hashLink(){                             //hashLink constructor
        start=NULL;
        tail=NULL;
    }
    void push(string key, float val);       //Function to push values to stack. Used if there is a collision.
};

void hashLink::push(string key, float val){ 
    struct hashNode *ptr;
    ptr = new hashNode;
    ptr->key = key;
    ptr->val = val;

    ptr->next = NULL;
    if(start != NULL){
        ptr->next = tail;
    }

    tail = ptr;

    return;
}

struct hashTable{                           //The "hash table." Creates an array of Linked Lists that are indexed by the values returned by the hash function.
    public:
    hashLink hash[50];
    hashTable(){                            //Constructor

    }
    void emplace(string in, float val);     //Function to insert a new key and value into the table.
    float fetch(string in);                 //Function to retrieve a stored key.
};

void hashTable::emplace(string in, float val){
    int i = hashU(in);                      //Retrieve index of key from hash function.
    hashNode *trav;                         //Create node traveler
    trav = hash[i].start;                   //Set the traveler to the start of the desired linked list

    while(trav!=hash[i].tail){              //Traverse the list searching to see if the input key already exists
        if(trav->key.compare(in)==0){       //If the input key already exists, its associated value is updated, and the function returns.
            trav->val = val;
            return;
        }
        else                                //Travler moves to next node if the input key in not found.
            trav = trav->next;
    }

    hash[i].push(in,val);                   //If the traveler does not see the input key, the request key must not exist and must be created by pushing the input key and associated value to the stack.

    return;
}

float hashTable::fetch(string in){          
    int i = hashU(in);                      //Retrieve index of key
    hashNode *trav;                         //Create node traveler and set it to the start of the appropriate list.
    trav = hash[i].start;

    while(trav!=hash[i].tail){              //Traverse the linked list searching for the requested key.
        if(trav->key.compare(in)==0){       //If the the requested key is found, return the associated value.
            return trav->val;
        }
        else
            trav = trav->next;              //If not found in the current node, move to the next.
    }

    return false;                           //If the requested key is not found, return false.
}

int main(){
    hashTable vars;                         //initialize the hash table
    float num = 5.23;                       //create test variable

    vars.emplace("KILO",num);
    cout<<vars.fetch("KILO")<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call "in.c_str()" to convert "in" to a string? Would save you having to allocate memory.

Comment: In `hashU`, which is such a short piece of code, I can find 2 unnecessary copying, 1 unsafe owning pointer (with a lot of illogical operations), 1 cryptic writing of `for` statement. The memory leak is just a consequence; the real problem is code quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `delete[] v`, you have advanced `v` such that it is pointing to the `0` at the end of the string, which is the wrong address to delete.

Also, you're wasting a lot of code unnecessarily copying the string out of where it is already available as a c-string.

```
unsigned int hashU(string in/*, int M*/) {
    const char* v = in.c_str();
    unsigned int h, a = 31415, b = 27183;
    for(h=0;*v!=0;v++,a=a*b%(49-1))
        h = (a*h + *v);
    return h % 50;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(h=0;*v!=0;v++,a=a*b%(49-1))
    h = (a*h + *v)%50;

delete[] v;                             //Delete the char* to prevent leaky
```

You are incrementing v, then deleting an invalid memory location.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks!